# SESSION variable isn't sending data to next page with datatable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to send the selected record of a gridview to the next page to populate the controls using Session with datatable.
I have added breakpoints and can see the datatable is populating but it does not seem to be sending over to the next page. Please Help.

Page one VB Code

```
Protected Sub grdClientlist_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles grdClientlist.SelectedIndexChanged

    If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
        dt.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn(20) {New DataColumn("clientid"), New DataColumn("name"), New DataColumn("surname"), New DataColumn("type"), New DataColumn("status"), New DataColumn("assistant"), New DataColumn("companyname"), New DataColumn("telephoneno"), New DataColumn("mobileno"), New DataColumn("faxno"), New DataColumn("email"), New DataColumn("streetaddress"), New DataColumn("streetaddress2"), New DataColumn("streettown"), New DataColumn("streetcountry"), New DataColumn("streetpostalcode"), New DataColumn("postaladdress"), New DataColumn("postaladdress2"), New DataColumn("postaltown"), New DataColumn("postalcountry"), New DataColumn("pospostalcode")})
        dt.Rows.Add(grdClientlist.SelectedRow.Cells(0).Text, grdClientlist.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text, grdClientlist.SelectedRow.Cells(2).Text, grdClientlist.SelectedRow.Cells(3).Text, grdClientlist.SelectedRow.Cells(4).Text, grdClientlist.SelectedRow.Cells(5).Text, grdClientlist.SelectedRow.Cells(6).Text, grdClientlist.SelectedRow.Cells(7).Text, grdClientlist.SelectedRow.Cells(8).Text, grdClientlist.SelectedRow.Cells(9).Text, grdClientlist.SelectedRow.Cells(10).Text, grdClientlist.SelectedRow.Cells(11).Text, grdClientlist.SelectedRow.Cells(12).Text, grdClientlist.SelectedRow.Cells(13).Text, grdClientlist.SelectedRow.Cells(14).Text, grdClientlist.SelectedRow.Cells(15).Text, grdClientlist.SelectedRow.Cells(16).Text, grdClientlist.SelectedRow.Cells(17).Text, grdClientlist.SelectedRow.Cells(18).Text, grdClientlist.SelectedRow.Cells(19).Text, grdClientlist.SelectedRow.Cells(20).Text)

        Session("client") = dt
        Response.Redirect("ClientDetails.aspx")


    End If


End Sub
```

Page 2 VB code

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Session("dt") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim dtclient As DataTable = New DataTable()
        dtclient = CType(Session("client"), DataTable)

        txtClientNumber.Text = dtclient.Rows.Item("clientid").ToString
        txtName.Text = dtclient.Rows.Item("name").ToString
        txtSurname.Text = dtclient.Rows.Item("surname").ToString
        cboClientType.Text = dtclient.Rows.Item("Type").ToString
        cboClientStatus.Text = dtclient.Rows.Item("status").ToString
        txtAssisstant.Text = dtclient.Rows.Item("assistant").ToString
        txtCompanyName.Text = dtclient.Rows.Item("companyname").ToString
        txtContactTel.Text = dtclient.Rows.Item("telephoneno").ToString
        txtMobileNo.Text = dtclient.Rows.Item("mobileno").ToString
        txtFaxNo.Text = dtclient.Rows.Item("faxno").ToString
        txtEmailAddress.Text = dtclient.Rows.Item("email").ToString
        txtStreetAddress.Text = dtclient.Rows.Item("streetaddress").ToString
        txtStreetAddressL2.Text = dtclient.Rows.Item("streetaddress2").ToString
        txtStreetAddressSuburb.Text = dtclient.Rows.Item("streettown").ToString
        txtStreetCountry.Text = dtclient.Rows.Item("streetcountry").ToString
        txtStreetPostalCode.Text = dtclient.Rows.Item("streetpostalcode").ToString
        txtPostalAddress.Text = dtclient.Rows.Item("postaladdress").ToString
        txtPostalAddressL2.Text = dtclient.Rows.Item("postaladdress2").ToString
        txtPostalAddressSuburb.Text = dtclient.Rows.Item("postaltown").ToString
        txtPostalCountry.Text = dtclient.Rows.Item("postalcountry").ToString
        txtPostalPostalCode.Text = dtclient.Rows.Item("pospostalcode").ToString
    End If

End Sub
```

I have tried indexing the row and also not indexing the row both same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If Session("dt") IsNot Nothing Then
```

Change this line to the following:

```
If Session("client") IsNot Nothing Then
```

Comment: Hi I changed that but still the same result nothing is populating across?

Comment: Ok, got it to work, cleared all cookies and seems like it is up and running now, Thanks for the help

Comment: @Terence you are welcome. And close your question please.

Answer (score 0):

The code for your second page is referencing the session variable by an incorrect name. In your first page you do:

`Session("client") = dt`

This assigns the DataTable `dt` to the session variable `client`. Top get back to this data from the second page (as has already been pointed out) you will need to reference `Session("client")`, which is what now holds your data. The original variable `dt` of type DataTable was destroyed as soon as the browser was done rendering the 1st page.